# vscode, debug angular, first time, doesn't debug, 2nd time stops at main.js then it's ok

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code

when I launch chrome to debug an angular 17+ app, the debugger does not work. If I refresh then it stops at main.js, if I move forward from there it debugs from there.

here is my launch configuration.

```
"configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Launch Chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "type": "chrome",
      "url": "http://localhost:4202",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
    },
```

And my angular.json.  I did have problems with the cache in the past.

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "cli": {
    "cache": {
      "enabled": false
    },
    "analytics": false
  },
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "client": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:application",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/client",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "browser": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": ["zone.js"],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": ["src/favicon.ico", "src/assets"],
            "styles": [
              "@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css",
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "prod": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "500kb",
                  "maximumError": "1mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                  "maximumError": "4kb"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ]
            },
            "development": {
              "optimization": false,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.development.ts"
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "buildTarget": "client:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildTarget": "client:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "buildTarget": "client:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-builders/jest:run",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": ["scss"],
            "assets": ["src/favicon.ico", "src/assets"],
            "styles": [
              "@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css",
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

it's vscode V1.86.2

what should I look for?